# How to render a batch action in ActiveAdmin including a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I display a list of trips in admin/trip, for the selected trips I have a batch action which generate a pattern of html code of a newsletter (completed with informations from the selected trips).

```
batch_action :batch_action, method: :post do |ids|

#my process

render "admin/trips/generate_newsletter.html.erb"
```

That works. However in the view, just before the html code I have a form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag({action: "batch_action"}, class: "formtastic") do %>
```

The form only contains a text_area where the admin can add a comment for the newsletter. The idea is that when we send the form, the page is refreshed, keeping the trips selected and adding the admin comment into the html code.

Now when I submit the form I get an error: ' Couldn't find batch action "" '.

The variable @_params contains:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"pzqtPMxhB9G83UYad2olCF4O79cK4+mf+R0VBOR61uo=", "admin_text"=>"Admin comment", "commit"=>"Ajouter", "action"=>"batch_action", "controller"=>"admin/trips"}
```

I've tried multiple things but I don't see the answer, maybe what I want to do is impossible this way.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveAdmin 1.0 provides a DSL for creating a custom form in a batch action.

[image]

In app/admin/trips.rb

```
batch_action :generate_newsletter, form: {
                                            comment: :text,
                                            send_now: :checkbox
                                          } do |ids, inputs|
  # load selected trips
  trips = Trip.find(ids) # selected trips

  # Generate Newsletter from trips array
  newsletter = Newsletter.create_from(trips)

  if inputs[:send_now] == 'on'
    # send generated newsletter
    NewsletterMailer.send_email(newsletter).deliver
    # return to admin/trips#index
    redirect_to collection_path, notice: 'Sent newsletter'
  else
    # show generated newsletter
    redirect_to admin_newsletter_path(newsletter), notice: 'Generated newsletter'
  end
end
```

However, I am not aware of a built-in method that keeps the IDs selected after the page refreshes. To compensate, I recommend creating a Newsletter populated with the selected trips (shown above). One could even make an association between Newsletter and Trips so that you can reorder or remove trips for a newsletter.

CITE: http://activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html